# Sweet alert toastre animation.. Fade In

Tags: sweetalert

I'm using SweetAlert v10.14.1 as a toastr with code

```js
<script>
const Toast = Swal.mixin({
      toast: true,
      position: 'top-right',
      showConfirmButton: false,
      timer: 5000,
    })
</script>
```

it works fine .. but the message dropped down from top with white background .. i want to :

1- fade it in and out

2- change apperance to a bootstrap theme

Answer (score 0):

No fade-in effect at the moment. If you want to remove the "boing" effect, you can just do it adding to your props:

```
Swal.fire({
    ... you other props...
    showClass: {
      popup: "", // it removes the 'boing' effect, the default value is 'swal2-show'
    },
});
```